# Circe encoder for generic ADT with context bound

Tags: scala, encoding, circe

I have the following setup:

```scala
  import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
  import io.circe.generic.extras.auto._
  import io.circe.syntax._

  implicit val Conf: Configuration = Configuration
    .default
    .withSnakeCaseConstructorNames
    .withSnakeCaseMemberNames
    .withDiscriminator("type")

  sealed trait Generator[T]
  case class UniformGenerator[T](min: T, max: T) extends Generator[T]
  case class EnumGenerator[T](values: Set[T]) extends Generator[T]

  sealed trait DataType
  case class IntType(generator: Generator[Int]) extends DataType
  case class StringType(generator: Generator[String]) extends DataType
```

Encoding these ADTs into JSON is working well, executing:

```scala
  println((IntType(UniformGenerator(1, 5)): DataType).asJson)
```

prints

```
{
  "generator" : {
    "min" : 1,
    "max" : 5,
    "type" : "uniform_generator"
  },
  "type" : "int_type"
}
```

However, when I want to restrict the generic type for one of the generators, for instance when I require the `UniformGenerator` to work only with `Numeric` types:

```scala
case class UniformGenerator[T: Numeric](min: T, max: T) extends Generator[T]
```

It fails with the following error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[DataType]
> println((IntType(UniformGenerator(1, 5)): DataType).asJson)

So, it can't derive the right encoder automatically. What is the reason for that and how can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: turns out **this answer is wrong** (or: only true for Scala 3 which the original question is not about). I made a wrong assumption about what circe does and does not support. See answer and comments by @sanyi14ka.

#### A) Reason(s)

To understand the reason(s), you need to understand that

```
class UniformGenerator[T: Numeric](min: T, max: T) extends Generator[T]
```

is just syntactic sugar for:

```
class UniformGenerator[T](min: T, max: T)(implicit ev: Numeric[T]) extends Generator[T]
```

So by adding the context bound, you add an additional parameter in an additional parameter list.

##### a) Main Reason: derivation does not support more than one parameter lists

You could try this by changing your case class definition to

```
case class UniformGenerator[T](min: T)(max: T) extends Generator[T]
```

That would also fail to compile (if you try to derive an `Encoder` for it) because derivation only supports case classes with one parameter list.

##### b) Additional reason: circe would need an `Encoder[Numeric[Int]]`

If derivation would support additional parameter lists, circe would need an `Encoder` for the new parameter - but there is no `Encoder[Numeric[Int]]` in scope (nor could it be derived).

#### B) Workarounds

As far as I am aware, there is no magic "fix" for this, but I could propose some workarounds:

##### a) Do not add the context bound to the case class

Depending on your use case, it might be acceptable to not add the context bound to the case class and instead add it to the functions that need it, e.g.:

```
def doSometingWithNumericUniformGenerator[T: Numeric](generator: UniformGenerator[T]) = // ...
```

##### b) Implement the specific `Encoder` manually

(the obvious solution)

##### c) Move the "context bound" into the main parameter list and provide an Encoder for it

You could make the third parameter explicit:

```
class UniformGenerator[T](min: T, max: T, n: Numeric[T]) extends Generator[T]
```

By adding another `apply` method to the companion, you could still construct it as usual:

```
object UniformGenerator {
  def apply[T: Numeric](min: T, max: T): UniformGenerator[T] =
    UniformGenerator[T](min, max, implicitly[Numeric[T]])
}
```

Then, you would need to somehow provide an

```
implicit val numericIntEncoder: Encoder[Numeric[Int]] = ???
```

Once you have that, derivation of an `Encoder[UniformGenerator[Int]]` should work.

Comment: Indeed, defining `(min: T)(max: T)` won't work, however it supports implicit parameters, and one doesn't have to define an encoder for the implicit parameter, to `Numeric[T]` in this case. See, my answer below. Removing the context bound is not an option for my use case, but luckily I managed to make it working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Interesting. I had thought they intentionally disallowed derivation for such implicit parameters to avoid running into situations like this one: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/3g4Y4NLQRGCvEZTkKW3jXQ

Comment: P.S: turns out that my answer would be true for the Scala 3 version of circe: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2OfOZDibQXW1r8uJCnYNyA

Answer (score 0):

I realized that circe wants to automatically and lazily derive an encoder for each possible ADT that can happen. If I restrict the generic type, then the `Encoder` for `Generator[String]` will fail. If we try to define it explicitly:

```scala
  implicit val stringGenEnc: Encoder[Generator[String]] = Encoder.instance {
    case UniformGenerator(min, max) => ???
    case EnumGenerator(values) => ???
  }
```

then it can't derive an encoder for `UniformGenerator`. However, we can define one encoder to help circe. For my use case it can be

```scala
  implicit val stringUnifGenEnc: Encoder[UniformGenerator[String]] = _ => Json.Null
```

and similar way one can define a decoder, too:

```scala
  implicit val stringUnifGenDec: Decoder[UniformGenerator[String]] = _ =>
    Left(DecodingFailure("uniform_generator for strings are not supported", List.empty))
```

Likewise, circe can automatically derive encoders and decoders for `DataType`, too.

Comment: Now that I finally understood the cause of your problem: you could as well just restrict `StringType` to `case class StringType(generator: EnumGenerator[String]) extends DataType`. There can never be a `StringType` containing any other type of `Generator` type, so why not restrict it like that to help derivation (and to avoid implementing those unreachable implicits that you suggested).